# Looking for good books on convex polyhedra theory

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra

My knowledge on convex polyhedra and systems of linear inequalities (facets, edges, Farkas Lemma, projections, duality, etc.) is very scattered, and I'l like to go through a book to solidify it.

I'm looking to something similar to chapters 3-4 in Integer Programming by Conforti, Cornuejols, and Zambelli, but with lots of good exercises.

I have gone through some of Bertsimas' *Introduction to Linear Optimization*, and I can't really put my finger on why, but I just don't like it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Ziegler's "Lectures on polytopes" is a great reference.